# NUnit debugging with VWD 2008 Express

Tags: debugging, nunit, vwdexpress

How can I do this?

Is it even possible?

I only see online tutorials for setting up debugging with NUnit for non express versions or for visual studio.

I have setup NUnit, I just can't seem to debug with it.

Answer (score 2):

One trick is to change the class library project containing the tests to a console application and then just create a main method for it.

Easy and effective.